# Cómo puedo tomar un enter por stdin y compararlo?

Tags: c

recien empiezo en el mundo de la programación y en este foro. Estoy haciendo este ejercicio que encontré por internet:

"Un programa que pregunte un nombre de fichero y muestre en pantalla el contenido de ese
fichero, haciendo una pausa después de cada 25 líneas, para que dé tiempo a leerlo. Cuando el usuario pulse intro, se mostrarán las siguientes 25 líneas, y así hasta que termine el fichero."

Yo simplifiqué el ejercicio al usar un .txt que no tenga espacios ni caracteres especiales, solo saltos de linea.

El problema está en la parte de tomar el teclado y esperar a que se ingrese el enter para continuar. Con algunas funciones como fgets el programa pasaba de largo de ella y seguía imprimiendo el archivo hasta el end of file. Con otras como el fscanf sí esperaba a que ingrese por teclado pero se me complicó comparar la string con el enter. Espero que me haya explicado bien.

El codigo que hice es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> //ya se que incluyo bibliotecas de más

int main ()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char frase[101];
    int flag = 0;
    char arch[35];
    char a [2];
    char i = 0;
    
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo a leer: ");
    scanf("%s", arch);
    
    fp = fopen(arch, "r");

    if (fp == 0)
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
        
    else 
    {
        
        while (flag == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            fscanf(fp, "%s", frase);

            if( !feof(fp) && !ferror(fp) )
            {
                printf("%s\n", frase);
                
                flag = 0;
                
                i++;
                
                    if ( (i % 25) == 0) 
                {
                    printf("Presione enter para continuar: ");
                    fgets(a,2,stdin); //Acá está el problema
                    flag = 1;
                    
                    if (a[0] == 10) //Esto lo pensé por el \n del ascii
            
                        flag = 0;
            
                    else
                    
                        printf("No se ingresó enter, se cierra el programa\n");
                }
            }
      
            else
                printf("Finalizó la lectura del archivo\n");
            
        }
    }
    
    fclose (fp);
    
   return 0;
    

}
```

Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ibas bien, pero usas las funciones que no tocan, por ejemplo `getchar()` encaja mucho mejor que `fgets()` para capturar la pulsación del intro, mientras que `fgets()` encaja mejor (SIEMPRE) que `fscanf()` para leer el flujo de un stream. Si quieres un consejo, declara las variables en el punto en que las vayas a necesitar, eso hará tu código mucho más legible para ti mismo y para los demás, dicho eso, yo lo haría tal que así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[101] = ""; // Inicializamos el array por si acaso ...

    printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo a leer: ");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
    {
        // Eliminamos el salto de línea
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(str, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        int n = 0;

        while (fgets(str, sizeof str, fp))
        {
            printf("%s", str); // No imprimimos \n

            char *ptr = strchr(str, '\n');

            // Solo incrementamos n si leemos el fin de linea
            if (ptr != NULL)
            {
                if ((++n % 25) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Presione enter para continuar");
                    getchar();
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp); // Cierra solo en caso de que se haya podido abrir el archivo
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias David, un abrazo